# Running a timer regardless if the activity is active or not

Tags: android, background, timer, notifications, alarmmanager

Ive created a timer which counts down and when it reaches 3 it starts vibrating stronger and stronger until at 0 it vibrates fully.

My problem is that if the user turns off the screen the timer becomes unstable, i.e. counting down unpredictably or not at all. After searching around for a while I found that the solution probably is to use the AlarmManager, however this seems very complex for such a simple task.

The timer should be tied to the activity and if set, a notification indicating the time left should also be fired.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear that timer will be unstable if you implement it in activity. It results from lifecycle of activity. Main activity element it's GUI thread which is not the best place to implements logical elements.

You should use alarm manager or implement your own service to manage action which will properly work in the background. You have problem because when you switch your screen of your app is paused and until you'll restart it you haven't full control about the action inside activity.

I'm a fan of programming using brain, so I give advices, not clear code. But I hope that it will help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options that you could consider to do what you're asking, and each one woudl depend on your specific circumstance and what you really want to achieve. A Service, an IntentService (Service subclass), AlarmManager, or a (partial) WakeLock (and maybe some more creative solutions that I'm missing).

I think the easiest thing out of the gate is to use a Partial WakeLock. It's dead simple, and is useful if you want a process to run in your activity even when the screen is off.  You have to use it sparingly though, as it will chew up battery life (which is why activities pause when the screen is off).

To use a WakeLock:

Add the permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

In your activity, start the WakeLock when you need it

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "WakeLockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

When you're done with the wakelock (i.e. don't need to run the process any more), release it:

```
wakeLock.release();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I decided to accept the other answer as it seems more like the "right thing" to do. And I didnt want to include another permissions just for this.